# Setting UITextField max length to match screen width?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

Hey all I am stumped on this one. I was wondering if there is a way to set the max length of a `UITextField` to match the width of the screen?

Comment: By "max length" are you referring to the number of characters in the text field?

Comment: do you use autolayout? if so you can just set the `width` constraint appropriately or the `leading & traling space`

Comment: @nburk i am referring to the max length of the characters within the `UITextField`, not the width of `UITextField`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in four steps:

1. Set the delegate of your `UITextField`
2. Get the new string, and calcul its width
3. Check if the string's width is out of the screen width
4. Enable or not the user to add more characters in your `UITextField`

---

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
            NSString *text = textField.text;
            text = [text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textField.font}];
            return textSize.width < textField.bounds.size.width;
  }
```